# how to do a full text search with php pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, search, pdo

So I'm having trouble with my current search for a website. So my current search will achieve this;
user inputs "crik" and it will return "cricket" for a search.
However if a user inputs "crickets" it wont return "cricket" for a search. 
How do I get this to work?
my current php code is;

```
      $searchQ = $_GET['search'];  
      $ssss = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM listing WHERE name LIKE :search');                                    
      $ssss->bindValue(':search', "%" . $searchQ . "%");        
      $ssss->execute();
```

I've also tried this but it didnt return anything;

```
$ssss = $pdo->prepare('SELECT  * FROM listing WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE) ');
```

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM listing WHERE name LIKE '%' + :search + '%' "`

Comment: What storage engine  has this table? And did you use fulltext  index?

Comment: storage engine is InnoDB i think and i dont know how to use a full text index. Sorry I'm new to php

Comment: Also xNeyte thanks for commenting but it didnt work, is it because i dont have to bindvalue after that statement?

Comment: It works here, yes you have to bindvalue your word 'crik' for example

Comment: `like` is not how you use a fulltext index. in order for your approach to work you have to run `create fulltext index ftx on listing(name)`

Comment: sorry yes it did not work. I had $ssss=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM listing WHERE name LIKE '%' + :search + '%' ");
then binded with
$ssss->bindValue(':search', $searchQ);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the search string

```
$searchQ = $_GET['search'];
$searchArr = str_split($searchQ );
$searchQ_new = "";
foreach($searchArr as $alpha)
{
        $searchQ_new .= $alpha . "%";
}
```

Now you can use your code to search with $searchQ_new

Answer (score 0):

If you want the input `crickets` to match name `cricket`, you can use the wildcards on name column as well, something like:

```
$ssss = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM listing 
                       WHERE name LIKE :search1 
                       OR :search2 LIKE CONCAT('%', name, '%')");
$ssss->bindValue(':search1', '%' . $searchQ . '%');
$ssss->bindValue(':search2', $searchQ);
```

Or shorter and more consistent (I'm not sure whether the binding will work this way, but you can try):

```
$ssss = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM listing 
                       WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', :search, '%')
                       OR :search LIKE CONCAT('%', name, '%')");
$ssss->bindValue(':search', $searchQ);
```